# HDF5 for Python: high level vs low level interfaces. h5py

Tags: python, performance, hdf5, h5py

I've been working with HDF5 files with `C` and `Matlab`, both using the same way for reading from and writing to datasets:

- open file with `h5f`
- open dataset with `h5d`
- select space with `h5s`

and so on...

But now I'm working with `Python`, and with its `h5py` library I see that it has two ways to manage HDF5: high-level and low-level interfaces. And with the former it takes less lines of code to get the information from a single variable of the file.

Is there any noticeable loss of performance when using the high-level interface?
For example when dealing with a file with many variables inside, and we must read just one of them.

Comment: In most cases, there shouldn't be a noticeable difference. Why not just profile it and see?

Comment: Profiling is one of the next things I'll do, but any other opinion from people that already faced this matter is always valuable!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

High-level interfaces are generally going with a performance loss of some sort. After that, whether it is noticeable (worth being investigated) will depend on what you are doing exactly with your code.

Just start with the high-level interface. If the code is overall too slow, start profiling and move the bottlenecks down to the lower-level interface and see if it helps.